# When should I call Geometry.computeBoundingBox() etc?

Tags: three.js

The Geometry class [documentation](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Core/Geometry) explains that bounding boxes and spheres need to be computed manually. But not why and when to do so.

Do they always need to be computed when a Geometry object is created or changed?

Or is it only if my code uses them?

What about computeCentroids(), computeFaceNormals(), computeVertexNormals(), computeMorphNormals(), and computeTangents()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I always call the required compute methods just after I ended adding vertices, faces, etc and before creating the mesh with the geometry:

```
   geometry.vertices.push(...);
   ...
   geometry.faces.push(...);
   ...            
   geometry.computeCentroids();
   geometry.computeFaceNormals();
   geometry.computeBoundingSphere();
   mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
```

I would say that if you are modifying your model on runtime you should call it after you finish the modification.

Comment: So computeCentroids(), computeFaceNormals() and computeBoundingSphere() are the required ones? Is this mentioned anywhere in the Three.js documentation?

Comment: Unfortunately it is not mention in the documentation, but in the majority  of samples that I have reviewed those are the methods that are called. I would recommend explore the examples available and check out the one that does something similar to whatever you want to do and call the same methods.

Comment: OK. That's easy enough to do in practice. I'd prefer to understand why and how, but I don't really have to.